# change html5 audio tag source did not work on android 4.1.2 chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html

I`ve searched the article and the following code works fine on desktop chrome.
But it failed on Android with chrome.
The toolbar has showed, but the play button was disabled.

**HTML5**

```
<audio controls>
<source src="sample1.mp3" id="audio_1">
</audio>
```

**JS**

```
$('#audio_1').attr("src","sample2.mp3");
$('#audio_1')[0].load();
```